# jQuery - toggle slide above div with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a "menu" and an "image" which toggles the menu. (FYI, I'm not using jQuery Mobile, I have tried and it messed everything up). Therefor I'm creating my own "sliding menu".

The only real problem is that it slides over my "image", but not over my content-div. It pushes it aside and I cannot seem to fix this. I want my "menu" to slide over all divs and actually be on top of everything.

HTML

---

```
<div class="menuopties">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Hello World</li>
            <li>This is me</li>
            <li>Saying hi</li>
            <li>To You</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="image"></div>
        <div class="innercontent">Some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

---

```
#image {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
#menu {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}
.menuopties {
    float: left;
}
#content {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.innercontent {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

jQuery

---

```
$("#image").click(function () {
    $("#menu").toggle("slide");
});

$("#menu").click(function () {
    $("#menu").toggle("slide");
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/27g9148y/2/)

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ap9y6zrr/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code `position:absolute;left:0;top:0;`

```js
$("#image").click(function () {
    $("#menu").toggle("slide");
});

$("#menu").click(function () {
    $("#menu").toggle("slide");
});
```

```css
#image {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
#menu {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.menuopties {
    float: left;
}
#content {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.innercontent {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuopties">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Hello World</li>
            <li>This is me</li>
            <li>Saying hi</li>
            <li>To You</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="image"></div>
        <div class="innercontent">Some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! The effect is even more awesome then what I had in mind :D Thank you!